Service Agent Account not created when cloud function API is enabled
The default service account 'service-${PROJECT_NUMBER}@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com' was created but immediately got deleted for unknow reason. This caused the cloud function deployment failed with the below error:
"error": ***
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Could not authenticate 'service-xxxx@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com': Account deleted: xxxx",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND"
  ***
***

I tried to re-enable cloud function API and also ran the followings but nothing worked:
gcloud services enable run.googleapis.com
gcloud services enable eventarc.googleapis.com

Expected behaviour: The service account needed for cloud function should be created

That service account is created when the service is enabled, ie: gcloud services enable cloudfunctions.googleapis.com. If the service account is being deleted, ask the team if there is a robot monitoring IAM and deleting the service account. You can also check IAM logging to see who/when the service account was deleted. Edit your post with more details after investigating.

Hi John, I checked the Log Explorer but nothing showed up. Under the principals it showed that the service account was deleted but could not find any history of what happened

The delete action is logged. Where did you look? https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit#admin-activity

I could not only find it when enabling the option 'Include Google-provided role grants'. I re-created the service account successfully so it's solved now. Thanks!
